# SAP-HANA Query execution is showing syntax error. Can anyone look in to this

Tags: database, hana

I am trying to execute this query:

```
DELETE from TABLE1A
WHERE X IN
   (SELECT A.X FROM
   (SELECT X, r1.Y, r2.Y, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION by r1.Y, r2.Y ORDER by X) as RANK
       FROM TABLE1B r0
       INNER JOIN TABLE1A r1 on r0.X = r1.X
       INNER JOIN TABLE1A r2 on r0.X = r2.X
       WHERE r1.Y = foo and r2.Y = bar
    ) AS A  WHERE A.RANK > 1
   );
```

After executing it, am getting the error: SQL Error [268] [HY000]: SAP DBTech JDBC: [268] (at 63): column ambiguously defined: X

What could possibly go wrong in that query?

Comment: "ambiguous" points to the problem that the column source table is needed to be explicitely defined in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Tables R1 and R2 both seem to have columns named `X`, but in the `ORDER BY` part on the window function you don’t specify which of these columns should be used; thus the error message.

Comment: also in the SELECT's field list